# Shift + Arrow combination in Visual Studio becomes word or document jumping

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In my Visual Studio, the Shift + Arrow combination becomes word jumping:

- Shift + Left = Jump to previous word
- Shift + Right = Jump to next word
- Shift + Up = Jump to document top
- Shift + Down = Jump to document bottom

Can someone tell me what's the name of the shortcut name of these combination in VS keyboard settings?

Comment: In key config options you can search by key combination if you enter it in the field without selecting any item in the list. Check different contexts: global, text editor etc.

Comment: It seems that the list item is selectd by default in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard. Are you mentioning another setting?

Comment: Nope. That's it. I just checked and it seems that even you have a list item selected you can still search by key. Just input some combination into "Pres shortcut keys" field and you will see the list of assignments for it in "Shortcut currently used by" dropdown. In your case, you are interested in "Text editor" context. See [image](http://s10.postimg.org/9wrkl32nd/keys.png)

Comment: OK, but the issue is the combination are not assigned to Text Editor, so I need to know what names like "Edit.XXX" should be chose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shift+Arrows:

- Edit.CharLeftExtend
- Edit.CharRightExtend
- Edit.LineDownExtend
- Edit.LineUpExtend

You probably mean Ctrl+Arrows:

- Edit.WordNext
- Edit.WordPrevious

See more in [Visual Studio keyboard binding browser](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2c3354bd-8efd-4ea7-9099-a5fd80ca4185)

Comment: Thanks I'll check. Now Ctrl+Arrow and Shift+Arrow are the same.

Comment: Don't know why but these settings for Text Editor is just missing. It's find now. Thanks.